# How to test if FileExists in folder where Inno Setup is running?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I determine whether a certain file exists in the same location where Setup.exe is running from?

i.e. something like this:

```
if (FileExists(App.Path + '\config_file*.txt') = True) then
```

Note: I don't want to know the folder into which the application is being installed, I want to know the folder from which `Setup.exe` is running (eg. "C:\Documents and Settings\Jennifer Cox") - in Visual Basic 
For example the equivalent of App.Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path from where the setup was executed you need to extract it from the [`{srcexe}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=srcexe) constant. To extract the path from a file you can use the [`ExtractFilePath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilepath) function so putting this together you can get something like this:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := AddBackslash(ExtractFilePath(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'))) + 'File.txt');
  if FileExists(S) then
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Is there any way to make FileExists - or FileSearch - find a file using a wildcard? I am trying to find a file which begins "config_file" and which ends ".txt" but will be something like "config_file2763547.txt", but I won't know the 2763547 bit.

Comment: Ask that as a new question, please. That is a good topic which might be useful to share with others and would be lost in comments.

Comment: OK will do
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132072/how-to-test-using-wildcards-whether-a-file-exists-in-inno-setup

Comment: Just use `{src}` instead of trying to extract the path from `{srcexe}`.  Much simpler.

Comment: @Miral, forgot on `{src}`. Please post that as answer. Andy, could you unaccept this post, please ? I'll delete it...

Comment: You shouldn't delete your answer.  Even if it's not the best answer, it's still a good answer, and may be useful to someone who has a peripherally related question.

Comment: @Miral, but my answer is actually a workaround for `{src}`. Your answer is accurate and thus mine should disappear ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`{src}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) to obtain the path (excluding filename) to the installer itself.  This is most commonly useful when using `[Files]` entries that have the `external` flag, but it can be used in `[Code]` as well, like so:

```
// procedure/function Whatever();
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := ExpandConstant('{src}\File.txt');
  // ...
end;
```