# How to test using wildcards whether a file exists in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to use `FileExists` or `FileSearch` (or any other Pascal function) to determine whether a file pattern exists in a given folder?

Eg:

```pascal
if (FileExists('c:\folder\*.txt') = True) then
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, there is no function that would support wildcards for checking whether a certain file exists or not. That's because both [`FileExists`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) and [`FileSearch`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesearch) functions internally use [`NewFileExists`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/CmnFunc2.pas#L203) function which, as the comment in the source code states, doesn't support wildcards.

Fortunately, there is the [`FindFirst`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findfirst) which supports wildcards, so you can write a function like follows for your task:

```pascal
[Code]
function FileExistsWildcard(const FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FindFirst(FileName, FindRec) then
  try
    Result := FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0;
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;
```

Its usage is same as of [`FileExists`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) function, just you can use wildcards for the search like describes the MSDN reference for the `lpFileName` parameter of the [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. So, to check if there's a file with `txt` extension in the `C:\Folder` directory you can call the above function this way:

```pascal
if FileExistsWildcard('C:\Folder\*.txt') then
  MsgBox('There is a *.txt file in the C:\Folder\', mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

Of course the file name to be searched may contain a partial name of the file, like e.g.:

```pascal
if FileExistsWildcard('C:\Folder\File*.txt') then
  MsgBox('There is a File*.txt file in the C:\Folder\', mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

Such pattern will match files like e.g. `C:\Folder\File12345.txt`.

Comment: If you are using any constant in the path then use ExpandConstant.  Like this: 
if FileExistsWildcard(ExpandConstant('{src}\\*.zip')) then